# I want my data upto 6 decimal places in impala

Tags: sql, database, impala, truncate

I have a double type column in impala
while I am trying to cut it upto some decimal places
I got this error
`ERROR: AnalysisException: No matching function with signature: truncate(DOUBLE, TINYINT`).
e.g `select truncate(cast(0.4893617021276596 as double),7);`

any workaround will be welcome

Answer (score 1):

You can use `round()`:

```
select round(col, 6)
```

If you actually want a truncate, then subtract 0.0000005:

```
select round(col - 0.0000005, 6)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `DECIMAL` type, it is possible to represent numbers with greater precision than the `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE` types can represent.

The maximum allowed `precision` and `scale` of the `DECIMAL` type are both 38.

`Precision` is the total number of digits, regardless of the location of the decimal point.

`Scale` is the number of digits after the decimal place.
To represent the number 8.54 without a loss of precision, you would need a
DECIMAL type with precision of at least 3, and scale of at least 2.

Example:
Note that the `DECIMAL(17,16)` type means there is a total of 17 digits, with 16 of them after the decimal point.

`DECIMAL(17,16)  3.1415926535897932`

You could `ALTER` your table with `DECIMAL` type as follow:

```sql
ALTER TABLE my_table CHANGE field field DECIMAL(precision, scale);
```

or as suggest @Gordon Linoff, you could use `round()` function.